# Colimit of $k$-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, limits-colimits

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a field and $I$ is a partially ordered set. Does the following colimit exists?
$$ \operatorname{colim}_{i\in I} A_i $$
How can it be described? (I mean like an analogue for (co)-limits of modules)

What about the limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, all limits and colimits of $k$-algebras exist. Limits are taken set-theoretically. To describe colimits it suffices to describe coproducts and coequalizers. The coproduct of $k$-algebras is the free product, and the coequalizer of two maps $f, g : A \to B$ is given by quotienting $B$ by the two-sided ideal generated by elements of the form $f(a) - g(a)$.

Comment: The poset is not said to be directed, however.

Comment: @Zhen: ah yeah, good catch.

Comment: So in case of an arbitrary poset there is no description of limit and colimit?

Comment: @Marco: I just gave a description. In a complete catgory every limit can be computed using products and equalizers, and dually in a cocomplete category every colimit can be computed using coproducts and coequalizers. This is a basic result in category theory and you can probably find it in any category theory textbook. Then above I told you what coproducts and coequalizers look like in algebras.